# Mobile-UXSDK-iOS Swift Sample Code Error: No such module 'iOS_Color_Picker'

Tags: dji-sdk

I downloaded the latest master of https://github.com/dji-sdk/Mobile-UXSDK-iOS (should be 4.11.1), installed the pods and inserted the Bundle Identifier and the App Key.

when compiling I get the error:

```
Mobile-UXSDK-iOS/Sample Code/SwiftSampleCode/UXSDKSwiftSample/MapWidget/CustomMapViewController.swift:10:8: No such module 'iOS_Color_Picker'
```

my pod install looked successful:

```
pod install
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Installing DJI-SDK-iOS (4.11.2)
Installing DJI-UXSDK-iOS (4.11.1)
Installing DJIFlySafeDatabaseResource (01.00.01.17)
Installing DJIWidget (1.6.2)
Installing iOS-Color-Picker (1.2)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
```

can anyone assist me on this error?

thanks a lot

Comment: never mind and sorry for the question, I probably only opened the project file and not the workspace file...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

used workspace file and all works